# How to drop [UTC] from a column table in KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

Trying to clean up some columns coming into Sentinel from syslog, and working on changing from UTC to local time.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
print dt=now()
| extend pacific_dt = datetime_utc_to_local(dt, 'US/Pacific')
| extend PacificTime = pacific_dt
| project-away dt
```

What I would expect is two columns, one named pacific_dt and another named PacificTime.  However, when the output is displayed, both column names are appended with [UTC].  Is there a way to remove the [UTC] text that's appended or a workaround to make a new column based on that data but not get the appended text in the column name?

Here's the example code and output.
[Query & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zw8Y.png)

Comment: I am not getting UTC. Check this [img](https://i.imgur.com/GHT3v62.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, all dates in KQL are stored as UTC.
*datetime_utc_to_local()* add an offset to the datetime, so it appears as a local time zone, however it is still a UTC date, just a different one.
If you now change your client display from UTC to local, you get an additional offset.

[image: UTC]

[image: PST]

Please note the following:

- The current UTC value now equals to the previous PST value.
- The current PST value has **double** offset (-8h x 2)

Bottom line -
Work with UTC, and let the client do the conversion to a local time zone.